# How to emit events properly?

Tags: node.js, events

I'm learning how to emit events using the NodeJS Event module but I'm struggling on a workflow interrogation.

I'd like to listen for new post created on a specific website using web scraping as it doesn't provide any other way.

For now, all I could find was by using a loop every X minutes and emit it once it notices a difference. But it involves a lot of inconvenience :

1. How to do it in a loop without blocking the whole script
2. That involves that you need to wait before continuing in the loop

So, how should you listen to events such as a new post? Is looking for differences at regular intervals a good practice?

Comment: you need to provide some code to have accurate recomandations

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO I'm looking for best practices to have the best workflow, it's not about code yet

Answer (score 0):

The scraping is not blocking the whole script : the loading itself is pretty asynchronous, only the parsing part is synchronous.

If the scraping action is done with a promise, you can run promisses in parallel with `promises.all`, you could also run **scraping** with setInterval that way it will be started at regular interval even if some of the scrapings are slow or even failing

If you really want to not block the eventloop at all, you can run a worker for each **scraping** process.